# Who is the daughter of women? Daniel 11:17

Tags: prophecy, daniel

Daniel 11:17 (NASB)

> 17 "He will set his face to come with the power of his whole
>   kingdom,bringing with him a proposal of peace which he will put into
>   effect; he will also give him the daughter of women to ruin it. But
>   she will not take a stand for him or be on his side."

1/ Who is the daughter of women?

2/What is the proposal for peace?

3/ "But she did not take a stand for him or be on his side". What may she had done?

Answer (score 1):

I believe Daniel 11:17's "daughter of women" (literal) is Cleopatra I (she's not the famous Cleopatra, VII). Another translation is "youthful daughter." I'm trying to understand the idea behind the Hebrew phrase. She appears to have lived only 28 years, 204 Before-Christ to 176. And having been given by her father Antiochus III, at age 11, to marry Ptolemy V, as part of Antiochus' plot to ruin (i.e. take over) Ptolemy's Egyptian kingdom---she's maybe the finishing touch, of Antiochus' "peace proposal" (literally: "upright ones or things") between Antiochus of Syria and Ptolemy. But she turned out to be loyal to her husband and "not able to stand for [her dad], was of no use to him." She was the sister of Antiochus IV who is a big type of the final Antichrist, for his war on the Jews and desecration of their temple during the time of the Maccabees (cf  11:21-35; 8:8-14, 21-26; 9:24-27; Mt 24:15; 2 Thes 2:3-12; Rv 9:11; 13:1-8; 19:19-20). To follow Daniel 11, one can read the history of the 'Greek Empire' (Javan) that came to be after Alexander the Great died, divided among four of his generals, with all the infighting and fighting up until Rome, the fourth empire spoken of in Daniel, takes over in the Mediterranean. It looks like Daniel deals with the four successive empires of Babylon, Persia, Greece, then Rome in regard to Israel's and Jewish (God-Incarnate's fleshly tribe and family) destiny. (And probably because of Daniel 11's level of detail, many unbeliever, even Hebrew, scholars claim laughably that Daniel wasn't written by Daniel nor in Daniel's time of around 500 Before-Christ)

Comment: @ Walter Smetana: Thank you for your effort +1. Regardless of what the scholars claim  , Jesus Christ’s own acceptance of Daniel’s prophecy is significant evidence of its authenticity.​—Mt 24:15; Daniel 11:31.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the passage of Daniel refers to the end times not the days of Cleopatra before Christ. Also, the term “Daughter of women” sounds very similar to me, to “Son of Man” (Jesus) so i believe this could be symbolic of the true church or a single female of the true church who will represent the body/church as the bride of Christ. In the end Christ is coming to get “his bride” the church so seeing as Jesus called himself the Son of Man, it’s possible to me that Daughter of Women could be His counterpart, his Bride, the Church

Answer (score 0):

The daughter of women is Israel and specifically in this context, it is the giving of the new covenant relationship of their Messiah to the gentiles since the Jews have rejected Him. But, the relationship will not bet”for Him”, since they (little horn “, will depart from His Word, changevHis laws, add traditions to His Word, declare he (little horn / papacy) represents god on earth, etc.